# Buttons are changing position inside GridLayout when changing text in Buttons

Tags: android, android-button, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout filled with buttons and the text changes quite often. And always after a text change, the buttons sometimes move up or down a little, even though they should not. I see also some coincidence with the size of the text in the button (I have autosizing text inside the button). I also spotted, that the extent of the movement rises with the height of the button.
There is a gif of the movements:

[image: Screenshots of movements of buttons]

There is also the fragment xml in which there are the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentTypeA">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="5"

        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="253dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="317dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="253dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="381dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="253dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="381dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="317dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="381dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="answerButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="317dp"

            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"/>
    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

If you need some more info, just write and I will add it. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid hard coding the dimensions in your `layout_height`, `layout_width` in your layout for the obvious reason that it's going be different for different devices.

To solve the 'button alignment' issues due to the different length of the buttons' text, use a combination of nested `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` attribute like this:

```
  <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="5"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="9sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp">

        <Button
          android:text="@string/button1"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"/>

        <Button
          android:text="@string/button2"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"/>

        <Button
          android:text="@string/button3"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"/>

      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        <!-- same as above, but for button 4,5,6 -->
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        <!-- same as above, but for button 7,8,9 -->
      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

The above layout works, but the 'text autosizing' does not.
To make it work, need to add the 'sizing' attributes to all buttons.
This can be done using custom style.

```
  <Button
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/max_height_btn"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>
```

```
  <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
    <item name="autoSizeMinTextSize">9sp</item>
    <item name="autoSizeMaxTextSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="autoSizeStepGranularity">2sp</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer even though it did not work without a change. I needed to set the height of a linearLayout to a concrete number and then set the height of the buttons to match_parent.